# running a sequential matlab code in parallel

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, nested-loops

I have tried to run this nested loops in Matlab using `parpool` and `parfor`, but it keeps giving error due to the way the nested loops variables are defined. Anyone can help me?

```
for(a=1:size(bench,1))
    for(d=1:size(bench,2))
        allGuesses = sampleModel(BNmodel_loo(a), bench(a,d).micaNorm, samples);

        predTable((index):(index+samples-1),:) = allGuesses(:,(BNmodel_loo(a).pca.length+1):end);

        dataSetId(index:(index+samples-1)) = d;
        appNames(index:(index+samples-1)) = bench(a,d).application;

        index = index+samples;
    end
end
```

Comment: Becuase of your `index` variable, you have to run all the loops in order, so `parfor` wont work. If you can come up with a way to calculate `index` just using `a` and `d` that might be enough to make it work. Actually, your usage of `allGuesses` might not work either if you are changing elements of it and accessing elements of it in different loops.

Comment: So literally, there is no way ? :(

Comment: If `samples` is constant then something like `index=((a-1)*size(bench,1)+d)*samples)` might work (you'd have to test that!). For `allGuesses`, I'm not sure, you **might** be able to make one of the loops a `parfor`, no guarantees.

Comment: yes sample is constant. OK thanks @David, I give it a try